# Extract image URL as a string using XPath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

I am not able to extract product image url from flipkart using xpath.

URL:https://www.flipkart.com/f-d-f550x-56-w-bluetooth-home-theatre/p/itmea2aspwcaxuaz?pid=ACCEA2ASHNDGV4DP

Goal is to extract the image url which src is containing.

In this case:https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/speaker/home-audio-speaker/4/d/p/f-d-a550x-original-imaea2ftzywquzrz.jpeg?q=70 should be the output.

Xpath which I am using is:

```
//*[@class="_2rDnao"]//img[@src]
```

Using the above xpath in chrome xpath helper it is giving me the desired output but when using in python script its coming as blank.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import os


request_headers = {
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0.15063; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Referer": "http://thewebsite.com",
"Connection": "keep-alive" 
}


webpage=requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/savehatke/p/itmea2aspwcaxuaz? 
pid=ACCEA2ASHNDGV4DP", headers=request_headers)
tree = html.fromstring(webpage.content)
raw_img=tree.xpath('//*[@class="_2rDnao"]//img')
```

EDIT: Added python code

Comment: where is the rest of your code? Are you using selenium?

Comment: @QHarr I have added the code.

Answer (score 1):

The image url is also located in a script containing json at the bottom.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/f-d-f550x-56-w-bluetooth-home-theatre/p/itmea2aspwcaxuaz?pid=ACCEA2ASHNDGV4DP')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find(id='jsonLD')
json = json.loads(script.text)
for obj in json:
    if obj['@type'] == 'Product':
        url = obj['image']

print(url)
```

Output is `http://rukmini1.flixcart.com/image/128/128/speaker/home-audio-speaker/4/d/p/f-d-a550x-original-imaea2ftzywquzrz.jpeg?q=70`

Comment: Do we have any other options without using Beautiful soup?

Comment: I couldn't find any api on the website that gathers this data, so this is the simplest solution I could come up with. You could always use Selenium (other answers), but that is more of a hassle and beautifulsoup is easier. All you have to do is run `pip install requests` and `pip install bs4` in your command line for this solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the same dimensions even by checking the page via your xpath. If you don't mind some variation in size (you can always adjust for dimensions) then it is easy enough to regex out from response.text

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.flipkart.com/f-d-f550x-56-w-bluetooth-home-theatre/p/itmea2aspwcaxuaz?pid=ACCEA2ASHNDGV4DP')
p = re.compile(r'image":"(.*?)"')
print(p.findall(r.text)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This solution is based on Selenium**
The xpath is correct. you will have to use get_attribute to get the text.

```
imgElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='_2rDnao']//img")
print(imgElement.get_attribute('src'))
```

the output is,

> https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/416/416/speaker/home-audio-speaker/4/d/p/f-d-a550x-original-imaea2ftzywquzrz.jpeg?q=70